# MySql: how to create temp table by using dynamic select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

As you can understand from the title I want to create a temp table by using a dynamic select statement. Here is my codes:

```
 declare  strwhere varchar(30);
if hour(now()) >= 16 and minute(now()) >=30 then
    set strwhere = ' day(now()) +1 ';
else 
    set strwhere = '  day(now()) ';
end if;
set @query = concat("select  pc.customerid,
                    deliverytimespanid,
                    pc.id,
                    ca.districtid,
                    pc.status,
                    pc.orderid,
                    deliverydatetime
                from packages as pc
                inner join  customeraddresses as ca on ca.id = pc.addressid
                where pc.status = 1
                and day(pc.deliverydatetime) =",strwhere,"
                and month(pc.deliverydatetime) = month(now()) 
                and year(pc.deliverydatetime) = year(now()) ");

prepare resultset from @query;
execute resultset;
deallocate prepare resultset;
create temporary table if not exists table2 as (select * from resultset);
```

It returns

> resultset doesn't exist.

How should I select the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the table with the `SELECT` statement. Also you can shorten your `WHERE` clause.

```
declare  strwhere varchar(30);
if hour(now()) >= 16 and minute(now()) >=30 then
    set strwhere = ' CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ';
else 
    set strwhere = '  CURDATE() ';
end if;
set @query = concat("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 AS
                    SELECT  pc.customerid,
                    deliverytimespanid,
                    pc.id,
                    ca.districtid,
                    pc.status,
                    pc.orderid,
                    deliverydatetime
                from packages as pc
                inner join  customeraddresses as ca on ca.id = pc.addressid
                where pc.status = 1
                and pc.deliverydatetime =",strwhere,"
                );

prepare resultset from @query;
execute resultset;
deallocate prepare resultset;
```